# Ajax post doesn't work, statusText: "error"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
$("#loginBtn").live('click', function () {
  var username = $('#usernameField').val();
  var password = $('#passwordField').val();

  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/Login',
        data: { username: username, password: password },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            var asd = result;
        },
        error: function(e) {
            var asd = e;
        }
 });
 });
```

and when i type e in chrome console i get this:

```
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
    arguments: null
    caller: null
    length: 0
    name: ""
    prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
fail: function () {
    arguments: null
    caller: null
    length: 0
    name: ""
    prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 0
statusCode: function ( map ) {
    arguments: null
    caller: null
    length: 1
    name: ""
    prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
statusText: "error"
success: function () {
    arguments: null
    caller: null
    length: 0
    name: ""
    prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

What is wrong? The error messages doesn't say that much to me. I won't reach the controller method but it wont give me the error 404 that it can't find the /Account/Login either.

Comment: Do it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/vLaTJ/2/, and tell us what you get in the console.

Comment: I think you need to quote the json content like this: `data: { 'username': username, 'password': password }`

Comment: @adeneo it doesnt write anything directly in the console. but if i write arguments in the console i get this: 0: Object
1: "error"
2: ""
callee: function () {
length: 3
__proto__: Object

Comment: Did you remember to wrap the code in document.ready

Comment: And stop typing in the console, the output you're getting has nothing to do with this.

Comment: okej! the code is in document.ready function like this: $(document).ready(function () {

@PellePenna quoteing didn't work

Comment: Try this -> http://jsfiddle.net/vLaTJ/3/, and see what happens.

Comment: "Click worked" and then "Ajax worked"

Comment: And nothing in the console ?

Comment: @adeneo Yeah it shows me the arguments in the console. But now i got the 500 internal server error instead

Comment: Then there's a server error ?

Comment: What does that even mean in this context? I just want to reach the method Login in the AccountController. I don't want to go to a server, just the method.

Comment: @adeneo i figured out that:

   private readonly UserService userService;

        public AccountController(UserService userService)
        {
            this.userService = userService;
        } 
that code in the controller stoped the ajax post to reach the method. How can i reach the userService without doing this? 

  bool validUser = this.userService.ValidateUser(username, password);

Thats the code thats uses the userService

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var DTO = { username: username, password: password };
```

now set the data in you AJAX call as

```
data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
```

This is the way we do it when the Controller method has the following signature.

```
public JsonResult Login(string username, string password)
```

Don't forget to add [json3.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.0/json3.js) as a fallback for older browsers.